# I'm coding a dataset for life expectancy. It says "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Year'"

Tags: python, dataset, with-statement

I have to create a code to print out the overall max life expectancy from a .CSV file and be able to print it out.

[image]

Link to CSV file: https://byui-cse.github.io/cse110-course/lesson11/life-expectancy.csv

Where am I going wrong?

```
import math
import csv

print()

with open("life-expectancy.csv") as data_set:
    for row in data_set:
        row = row.split(",")

        entity = row[0].strip()
        code = row[1].strip()
        year = int(row[2])
        life_expectancy = (row[3])

        max_life = -1
        min_life = min(life_expectancy)
        avg_life = sum(life_expectancy) / len(life_expectancy)

        max_country = ""
        max_year = max(year)
        min_country = min(entity)
        min_year = min(year)

        chosen_year = ""

print()
year_lookup = input(float("Enter the year of interest: "))
print()
if life_expectancy > max_life:

        max_life = life_expectancy
        max_country = entity

        print()
        print(f"The overall max life expectancy is:{max_life:.2f} from {max_country} in {max_year:.2f}.\n")
        print(f"The overall min life expectancy is:{min_life:.2f} from {min_country} in {min_year:.2f}.\n")
    
        if chosen_year == year_lookup:
            chosen_year = year_lookup
        print(f"For the year: {year_lookup}.\n")
        print(f"The average life expectancy across all countries was str{avg_life:.2f}\n")
        print(f"The max life expectancy was in {max_country} with {max_life:.2f}\n")
        print(f"The min life expectancy was in {min_country} with {min_life:.2f}\n")
```

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Have you read the error? what is unclear about it? What do you expect `int("Year")` to yield? Did you forget to skip the first row?

Comment: When posting text from a console, please post the text in text format, using the code formatting tool. An image of text is not ideal in a number of ways, and may cause the question to be off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your CSV file contains the column heading names:

```
Entity,Code,Year,Life expectancy (years)
```

You need to skip the normal processing for that line (ideally, you'd check the headings to make sure they're what you expect).  As it is now, it's trying to convert the year column from the first line of the file, so it's calling `int("Year")`, which of course results in an error.

Comment: Im still so new to python. Can you please elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @RP116 This has nothing to do with Python.  You have a data file.  Look at it.  Try to understand the format.  The first line contains column names.  The names are text, not numbers.  The rest of the lines contain data.   When processing it, in any language (or even by hand, as a human being), you need to skip the first line.  The "year" column of the first line contains the word "Year".  That's not a number.  It has nothing to do with Python.  It should be painfully obvious if you simply look at it.